# Using And/Or in Prolog

Tags: prolog

So I'm relatively new to prolog and I've came across some code on the internet which can be used to represent an And/Or node.

```
% a is an or node with successors b,c,d.
or(a,[b,c,d]).
% c is an and node with successor d,e,f.
and(c,[d,e,f]).
% d is a terminal (solvable) node.
goal(d).
```

I'm confused as to how this predicates could be used to find a solvable node.
And references to point me in the right direction would be marvelous

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the source for this? This is incomplete.

Comment: Yeah sure can you explain how its incomplete? @GuyCoder

Comment: It's incomplete because nobody has any idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: There's no definition of what you mean by *solvable* here. What result do you want from `goal(d)`? Just success or failure? Without any further inputs on the "solvability" or truth value of `a`, `b`, `c`, etc, how can this be determined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have found question 2 (c) from the University of East Anglia's School of Computing Sciences Main Series UG Examination 2013/14 (found using a quoted text search on Google), asking:

> Given an AND/OR tree specified by a set of Prolog clauses of the form
>
> ```
> % a is an or node with successors b,c,d.
> or(a,[b,c,d]).
> % c is an and node with successor d,e,f.
> and(c,[d,e,f]).
> % d is a terminal (solvable) node.
> goal(d).
> ```
>
> write a Prolog program whose main clause, `solve(X)`, succeeds if and only if `X` is solvable.

As background:

- An and-node is solvable if and only if all of its successors are solvable.
- An or-node is solvable if and only if at least one of its successors is solvable.
- A terminal node is solvable if it is a goal.

The Prolog program requested could look something like this:

```
%not necessary - without this solve_and([]) will be false anyway
solve_and([]) :- 
    false.

solve_and([H]) :- 
    solve(H).

solve_and([H|T]) :-
    solve(H),
    solve_and(T).

%not necessary - without this solve_or([]) will be false anyway
solve_or([]) :-
    false.

solve_or([H|T]) :-
    solve(H);
    solve_or(T).

solve(X) :-
    goal(X),
    !.

solve(X) :-
    and(X, A),
    solve_and(A),
    !.

solve(X) :-
    or(X, A),
    solve_or(A),
    !.
```

This works nicely from the perspective of a consumer - one that calls solve with X already grounded to check for correctness, but the cuts (`!`) make it a poor generator of solvable Xs. Removing the cuts from the solve rules should make the system bidirectional.

Comment: You don't really need `solve_and([]) :- false.` or `solve_or([]) :- false`. If you leave out the rule, then `solve_and([])` will not succeed by default. Also, are all of the cuts necessary?

Comment: @lurker Fair points - I've commented on the `solve_and([])` and `solve_or([])` predicates to indicate that they are not strictly necessary, but I prefer to have them just to indicate that I have considered the base case (which, when dealing with an exam, can be valuable in its own right). As for the cuts, they make the 'output' nicer IMO - I don't need to know how many ways a given or node is solvable, just if it is or isn't - similarly, in a larger programme, I wouldn't want to backtrack and have a previously solvable node appear unsolvable. Not strictly necessary, but personal preference.

Comment: @lurker how would you do it differently? It'd be nice to here two programmers perspectives on the matter

Comment: @JimAshworth try the query `solve(X)` and see if it provides all of the correct solutions for `X`. This illustrates why one must be careful about cuts.

Comment: @lurker absolutely true - I was writing this as a consumer, not a generator. I'll add a note to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

This particular problem wants you to write a predicate to determine if a given node is solvable. In other words, if you were to query `solve(z)` it would succeed or fail depending upon whether `z` were solvable.

You would start by writing out what the rules are. Jim Ashworth already did this in his answer, but I'll restate them here:

- Rule 1: Node X is solvable if node X is a goal
- Rule 2: Node X is solvable if X is the conjunction (and) of one or more nodes that are all solvable
- Rule 3: Node X is solvable if X is the disjunction (or) of one or more nodes, at least one of which is solvable

Let's start by simply writing this in Prolog.

```
% Rule 1
solve(X) :- goal(X).

% Rule 2
solve(X) :-
    and(X, Subgoals),
    all_solvable(Subgoals).

% Rule 3
solve(X) :-
    or(X, Subgoals),
    at_least_one_solvable(Subgoals).
```

Now we need to write predicates `all_solvable/1` and `at_least_one_solvable/1`:

```
% Auxiliary predicates used above

all_solvable([]).
all_solvable([Node|Nodes]) :-
    solve(Node),
    all_solvable(Nodes).

at_least_one_solvable([Node]) :- solve(Node).
at_least_one_solvable([Node, NextNode|Nodes]) :-
    (   solve(Node)
    ->  true
    ;   at_least_one_solvable([NextNode|Nodes])
    ).
```

You can see that this is almost the same as Jim's answer, which was completely in the right direction. I'm just providing some improvements from a Prolog perspective. For this reason, *I think Jim deserves the credit for the answer*. Differences, besides my choice of predicate names, are:

- I omitted absolutely failing goals as being superfluous
- I used the `p1 -> p2 ; p3` construct to handle the "succeed once" for the disjunctive case
- The `all_solvable/1` will succeed even if there are no subgoals (most general solution)
- I avoided cuts otherwise to allow for the general solutions to occur

Above, the `p1 -> p2 ; p3` construct behaves as `p1, !, p2 ; p3`. So for some cases, the cut is helpful, as Jim pointed out in his comment, that you are only looking for solvability once in this problem, not multiple ways of solvability. You can also find a way to use the `once/1` predicate to achieve this (you can look that one up as an exercise).

An alternative implementation for `all_solvable/1`:

```
all_solvable(Goals) :- maplist(solve, Goals).
```

Here, `maplist(solvable, Goals)` will succeed if and only if `solvable` succeeds for every element of the `Goals` list.

As with Jim's solution, this will tell you if a specific goal is solvable (although Jim's answer won't leave a choice point as my solution does):

```
| ?- solve(a).

true? ;

no
| ?-
```

An additional benefit of the above solution is that it answers the general query properly with all of the correct solutions:

```
| ?- solve(X).

X = d ? ;

X = a ? ;

no
| ?-
```

Comment: @mat I was trying to maintain some symmetry with `at_least_one_solvable` in that `all_solvable/1` was requiring at least one goal to succeed. Of course my comment about the `maplist/2` based solution being equivalent would then be incorrect. I think I need some coffee...